# Azure Insert multiple rows to table from the json

Tags: json, sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to automate the process of bulk inserting a json from API to SQL table. Json will look something like below with array.

```
[
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Orlando",
    "Age": "23"
},
{
     "Id": "2",
    "Name": "Keith",
    "Age": "24"
},
{
     "Id": "3",
    "Name": "Donna",
    "Age": "23"
}
]
```

I will have same columns in table as well `Id`, `Name` and `Age`. I have many json array response from different APIs in this json format with different column names. So I am looking for more generic way of inserting the records to the tables since json node name and column in table are maintained same. I am planning to keep response type to table name mapping in some configurations, So deciding the table to which record need to be inserted is not the problem.

I just want a approach where I can insert a json to table without specifying all the column names etc. I saw few [articles](https://integration.team/blog/logic-apps-sql-server-bulk-inserts-using-openjson/) which suggests to use OPENJSON where I need specify the column names, If I follow this approach I will end up creating multiple stored procedures for each json to tables. So suggest me a good approach for handling the scenario using Azure logic apps or functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet here.  SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.   This leaves Dynamic SQL.

Assuming you know the Destination Table and the Columns of the destination AND your JSON is rather simple:

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7624851475d77c79cc5b6f5c8289ba2b)**

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max) = '
[
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Orlando",
    "Age": "23"
},
{
     "Id": "2",
    "Name": "Keith",
    "Age": "24"
},
{
     "Id": "3",
    "Name": "Donna",
    "Age": "23"
}
]   
'

Declare @Dest varchar(max) = 'YourTable'
Declare @Cols varchar(max) = '[Id],[Name],[Age]'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='

Insert Into ' +@Dest+' (' +@Cols+ ')
Select '+@Cols+'
 From (
        Select RN = A.[Key]
              ,B.[key]
              ,B.[value]
         From OpenJson('''+@JSON+''')  A
         Cross Apply OpenJson(A.Value) B
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for [key] in ( '+@Cols+' ) ) pvt
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

[image]